# ASP.net GIF in loader div does not playback even if it is properly called

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently learning the basics of asp.net and coding it in code behind.
In this project, I want to show a loading div while a long server process is executing. I achieved this by setting 2 functions on my button. onClientClick points to a javascript function that enables the div and onClick points to a CodeBehind function wherein I added a delay to simulate long server process and from there calling a javascript function to hidden the loading div. the whole process works but my problem is that the gif image in the loading div does not play at all (its a circle progress gif; doesn't rotate).

**html**

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Default.aspx">HOME</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="second.html">SECOND</a></li>
             <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="third.aspx">THIRD</a></li>
         </ul>
</nav>

<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />

    <asp:Button ID="aspbtn" Text="ASP Button" OnClick="aspbtn_click" OnClientClick="asd();" runat="server"></asp:Button>

</form>
<div>
    <p> The download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>
</div>

<div id="loadss" class="LockOn"></div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rawr);      
</script>
```

**javascript**

```
function rawr(){ 
    document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "none";

}
function asd() {
    document.getElementById("loadss").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("loadss").style.display = "block";
}
function meow() {
    asd();
    time(rawr);
};`enter code here`
```

**CodeBehind**

```
        Protected Sub aspbtn_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Add Fake Delay to simulate long running process.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "ToggleScript", "rawr()", True)


End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Here is a gif of what I am talking about

Edit2:
Still haven't found an answer/workaround

[image]

Comment: "the whole process works." so the only problem is that the gif doesn't rotate?

Comment: yes, that's the problem